# dired function i wrote passes only current marked folder at point, can i send all marked folder?

Tags: dired, shell

i have this simple function i wrote (tbh i have zero coding skills.i gathered stuff from the web :)):

```
(defun z/dired-media-filebot (file)
(interactive (list (expand-file-name (dired-file-name-at-point))))
(start-process "filebot" nil "filebot" file))
```

problem is it always send only the current marked folder at point while i want to send all marked folders. How does one send all marked folders?

Comment: Try reading other functions which act on marked files and see how they do it.

Comment: Look like `!` (`dired-do-shell-command`) can already achieve what you are trying to do